# What kind(s) of mathematical closure(s) is the computer science concept of "closed predicates" related to?

Tags: terminology, computer-science

In computer science, there is the (possibly informal) concept of writing predicates that are "closed".  For example I might write (pseudocode):

```
i = 1;
while ( i != 23 ) {
   ...
   i = i + 1;
}
```

This is **not** closed, because I could have something in the loop that results in *i* skipping over the value of 23.

What I should have written is a closed conditional expression such as the following:

```
while ( 0 < i && i < 23 )
```

All the desired values make the expression true, and all the undesired values make it false, and there are no extra values left unspecified: thus it's closed.

Can someone explain which types of mathematical closure are related to this concept, and a little bit about how they relate?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "closed" here. Can you give a reference to a CS text which defines it in more detail? (At present my best guess is "fully written out," but that doesn't seem right.)

Comment: @noahschweber, Tonight, I will look over some texts and see if that's where I got the term.  I'm a practicing software engineer with 30 years experience; I probably remember no more math than a first-year engineering student would know (basic algebra and trig, simple derivatives and integrals).  Consider my use of the term "closed" as a purely informal, not-at-ALL-rigorously defined concept!

Comment: @Forbin So what exactly are you looking for? I'm pretty sure there is no standard canonical terminology referring to the brand of closure you are alluding to here, so how can we help you.

Comment: @DonThousand, thanks for asking.  I'm trying to learn a little more about math fundamentals.  I'm afraid I can only offer a weak, colloquial definition of the brand of closure that I'm talking about.  If a conditional (or set of conditionals, for example in an "if-elseif-else" construct) is closed, then there are no possible values or states left unaccounted-for.  If it's open, there are values or states that you haven't mentioned explicitly, and if the program encounters those values or states, it might not do what you meant it to.

Comment: I started reading about various kinds of mathematical closure, and it intuitively seems that some of those are related to the concept I'm talking about.  But I lack the mathematical grounding to be able to work out for myself which "flavor" of closure is most closely related to this.  I was hoping one of you mathematicians would be able to look at it and say, "oh, you're talking about _____ closure, it's one and the same with your kind of closure because ______."

Comment: I'm a professional software engineer with about 20 years of experience programming and I don't recall anyone using "a closed predicate" in this sense, and it would not be immediately obvious to me what is intended. For case analyses, especially in functional languages like SML, O'Caml, or Haskell, I've heard "exhaustive" which means all cases are covered.

Comment: @DerekElkins, "exhaustive" might be the better term in SE... however, what launched me on my search was, in fact, the use of the term "closed" and my notice that it seemed related to one or more of the mathematical concepts of closure.  It's the concept I'm interested in, and less the terminology.  Don edited the tags I used, and I wish to leave them that way as he understands more of what the members of this group will be looking for than I do.